Converting from apidoc to swagger not working
I tried to use https://github.com/amanoooo/apidoc-swagger-3 to convert from apidoc to swagger in my project but I can't, I think I can't understand how should I use it.
Can someone who use it, give me an example how to use it, please?
I expect that the command npx apidoc-openapi-3 works and give me an result, but I got an error:
{"Block":1,"Element":"@constructor","File":".\node_modules\kuler\index.js","Source":"@constructor","level":"error","message":"Undefined error."}
undefined:1
undefined
^
SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse ()
at main (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\1b6d1448cbd618b9\node_modules\apidoc-openapi-3\lib.js:33:27)
at Object. (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\1b6d1448cbd618b9\node_modules\apidoc-openapi-3\bin.js:110:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
Node.js v21.6.1
